# Open-source CUDA IDE

Tags: open-source, ide, cuda

Could you recommend any open source (apart from eclipse) CUDA IDE that can be used directly (no additioanl plugins, etc)?

PS: therey is also any online-cloud CUDA IDE? (I found http://ideone.com/8lYvf, but not valid for CUDA)

Comment: Maybe this is interesting to you: http://www.nvidia.com/object/gpu-cloud-computing-services.html GPU Cloud Computing Service Providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QT-Creator, it works quite well in combination with cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)

project(GPU_PROJECT)
#set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

#In case findCUDA.cmake wasn't found, download it from here
# https://gforge.sci.utah.edu/gf/project/findcuda/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2F*checkout*%2Ftrunk%2FFindCuda.html 
# and put it into SOURCE_DIR/CMake
#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

#### Cuda 
# find_package(CUDA)
find_package(CUDA 3 QUIET REQUIRED)
# find_package(CUDA 2.1)
# find_package(CUDA 2.2)
# find_package(CUDA 2.3)
# find_package(CUDA 2.1 REQUIRED)
# find_package(CUDA 2.2 REQUIRED)
# find_package(CUDA 2.3 REQUIRED)
# find_package(CUDA 2.1 EXACT)
# find_package(CUDA 2.2 EXACT)
# find_package(CUDA 2.3 EXACT)
# find_package(CUDA 2.1 EXACT REQUIRED)
# find_package(CUDA 2.2 EXACT REQUIRED)
# find_package(CUDA 2.3 EXACT REQUIRED)
# find_package(CUDA 2.2 EXACT QUIET REQUIRED)

if (CUDA_FOUND) 
message(" * CUDA ${CUDA_VERSION} was found")
else(CUDA_FOUND)
    message(" * CUDA is not found")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Not all CUDA libraries are found")
endif(CUDA_FOUND)


set(SRCS
     src/main.cpp
     src/cuda_core.cu
)
cuda_add_executable(GPU_PROJECT ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(GPU_PRJECT ${SOME_LIBRARY})
```

If you want to have additional debug functionalities, replace gdb with cuda-gdb in the QT-Creator config.

Comment: as far as CUDA is concerned qtcreator turns from IDE to a text editor. You have no code model, no debugger (latest stock cuda-gdb does not work in qtcreator now), basically nothing.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=57297) is a guide on how to configure Netbeans for CUDA development.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Visual C++ Express (Not Open Source but Free)

If you are using CUDA 3.2 You will need VC++ 2008
If you are using CUDA 4.0RC You can use VC++ 2010